# Spring rest fileupload working from eclipse but not after deploying in production

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have red all the posts relating to uploading file using ajax to a spring mvc controller, but non of them was of help to my strange case! here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestHeader(value = CrossAppConstants.TOKEN_HEADER) String token, @RequestHeader(value = CrossAppConstants.NAME_SPACE) String nameSpace, @RequestHeader(value = CrossAppConstants.APP_KEY) String appKey, @RequestHeader(value = CrossAppConstants.APP_SECRET) String appSecret) {
    LOGGER.info("got file request");
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            final File tmp = new File(name);
            LOGGER.info("file '" + name + "' is being processed");
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmp));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            final String url = cloudStorageManager.putFile(name, file.getContentType(), tmp);
            tmp.delete();
            LOGGER.info("file '" + name + "' uploaded to " + url);
            return url;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.");
    }
}
```

and here is my client javascript:

```
$('.file-field').each(function() {
        var path_input = $(this).find('input.file-path');
        $(this).find('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
            var baseUrl = "myURL";
            path_input.val($(this)[0].files[0].name);
            path_input.trigger('change');
            var myFormData = new FormData($(this)[0].files[0]);
            myFormData.append('name', $(this)[0].files[0].name);
            myFormData.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]);
            var token = mytoken;
            var namespace = mynamespace;
            $.ajax({
                url : baseUrl + '/storage/upload',
                headers : {
                    'X-Auth-Token' : token,
                    'X-NAME-SPACE' : namespace,
                    'X-APP-KEY' : '',
                    'X-APP-SECRET' : '',
                },
                type : 'POST',
                cache: false,
                processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                dataType : 'text',
                data : myFormData,
                success : function(jsonData) {

                },
                error : function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

This code works perfectly in eclipse! but when I deploy my application I get 400 (Bad request) message with no information at all! also I noticed it does not reach my code in the controller "LOGGER.info("got file request");" but the user is authenticated successfully with no errors/exceptions thrown in the server side...

Comment: could it be because the url variable is not the full path.. `url : baseUrl + '/storage/upload'`..

Comment: Nop, i traced it already and it is the something like this : http://myserver.com/api/v1/storage/upload which is correct, the only trace I get in js console is 
400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:
4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4

Comment: `var baseUrl = "myURL";` should this be...? `var baseUrl = myURL;`

Comment: if still no luck, you can add an interceptor in spring to check if the request is coming to spring..

Comment: can you please tell me how to write that interceptor?

Comment: first of all, one thing is still bothering me.. I believe the url you are passing to the ajax call is not correct.. you are moving the string literel `myURL` to `baseUrl`.. is this exactly what you doing? pls print url somewhere to check it is having the correct value...        Then to create an interceptor, you just need to implement a class using the interface, `HandlerInterceptor`. That will ask you to implement few methods... In your case you can put some displays in the `preHandle` method. If the request is reaching spring, definitely that will be displayed.

Comment: sry.. you also need to add the mapping in spring-servlet xml.. 
Pls follow this guide.. http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter .. or google for better one...

Comment: this is driving me crazy! it gets to server, no exceptions it enters pre and after but I still get 400 on the client!
INFO: Authenticating user...
RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor preHandle
INFO: Request URL::http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/storage/upload
RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor preHandle
INFO: { "name" : [ "creative.jpg"]}
RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor afterCompletion
INFO: Request URL::http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/storage/upload
RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor afterCompletion
INFO: Request URL::http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/storage/upload :: Time Taken=13

Comment: For the URL I had to remove the code from the snippet, I check environment and return the correct URL and that works fine for all other controllers...

Comment: For the intercepter, even though it enters pre and after handlers it does not enter my method! At all!

Comment: are you using spring boot? else have you added any `multipartResolver` in you `spring-servlet.xml`?

Comment: could there be any firewall or any network related configs that is blocking this file upload? If request is reaching spring, it could be a network related issue... Are you in a corp network?

Comment: - yes am using org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver
- no, because it is also occurring on my machine if I deploy on jetty locally!
- to confuse me even more, I just tried deploying in apache-tomcat-8 and it worked @_@. where do you think I should look?!

Comment: Oh.. That is confusing... I don't think the issue is with application itself...